# Datastore Backup Error message - Domain isn't using G Suite

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I want to take regular backups of datastore. I tried opening 'Datastore Admin Panel' but I keep getting this error message.

> Server error Sorry, you've reached a login page for a domain that
>   isn't using G Suite. Please check the web address and try again.

What steps should I take to fix it, I have no clue right now to take any steps.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you still experiencing this error?

Comment: Yes. I just checked and this error hasn't gone.

Answer (score 0):

Admin Panel is [deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/datastore-backing-up-restoring). You can do backups using [the managed export and import service](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities).